# Prevalences to Odd's Ratios with 95% Confidence Interval

Tags: r

I want to conduct a meta-analysis with Odds Ratios. I have a list of 19 studies, which only report prevalences. It is always one prevalence for the exposed group and one reference prevalence for the non-exposed group. How do I calculate ORs and corresponding Confidence Intervals?

```
or_prevalences <- prevalence_calc$prevalences / (1 - prevalence_calc$prevalences) / 
  (prevalence_calc$ref_prevalences / (1 - prevalence_calc$ref_prevalences))
```

this is how I calculated the Odds Ratios

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.